# Cannot find namespace 'NodeJS' also with types node

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, node-modules

I get this error in my web application

```
ERROR in node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.d.ts:600:21 - error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'NodeJS'.

600 declare var global: NodeJS.Global;
```

As you can see here below i already added the `types": ["node"]` property but it's still not working

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "types": ["node"],
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true
  }
}
```

I don't really know how solve it. The applicationn starts the first time getting `Cannot GET /` and then, after saving whatever file, it works but still with the NodeJS error. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

For those who have this kind of problem i solved updating zone.js at version `"zone.js": "^0.11.1"`

Answer (score 0):

While upgrade angular 8 to 13 i am facing same. Because zone.js not installed to my project. so install zone js the problem resolved.

```
npm i zone.js
```